# How to fix datepicker error in Primefaces 12

Tags: jquery, primefaces

I'm upgrading to PF 12 from 11. I found an issue that was done on PF 12 https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/8914 to Optimize JS bundling.
I see that datepicker has been moved from jquery-plugins.js to calendar.js.
So I added calendar.js and the datepicker works fine, but now I get "Uncaught TypeError: u._base_updateDatepicker is not a function" from calendar.js.

```
javascript 176:325 Uncaught TypeError: u._base_updateDatepicker is not a function
```

Without adding calendar.js I'm not getting the error. i have used the file from PF.

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="calendar/calendar.js"/>
```

Any idea why I get this error? Do I miss some files? Thanks, any advice appreciated.

Comment: DatePicker works in the showcase. Please provide a [mcve]. See https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test

Comment: @oveb I believe this turned out to be a JS ordering issue in your code correct?

Comment: In our app, come  forward  'u._base_updateDatepicker is not a function' error too. In our case wrapped c:if tag-s caused this behavior.

Comment: thx for pointing out the calendar.js

Comment: Yes it was a ordering issue.